# COM+ Application Installation in Component Services

Tags: com+

Windows Server 2008 (32 bit)
IIS 7
Both applications referred to herein use the same hardware/system configuration.

I am (constantly, I am in System Test) installing the same Web applications in new test environments.

Two of those come with COM+ applications that have to be installed/registered in Component Services. I wrote a utility "comadmin" that does this from the command line. The command line utility is then used by the automated build tool that sets up and configured the Web application.

For one of my applications this always works.

But for the other the COM+ applications are more problematic. The applications (three of them) get installed but don't work (i.e. when the Web application attempts to use them it fails) and cannot be started or stopped (in the Component Services applet).

According to the build automation tool log file the comadmin command (see above) is called correctly (and in the same way as for the other Web application where everything works) and also sends the correct answer about having installed the COM+ application in question.

And deleting the COM+ applications and copying and pasting the exact same commands from the log file into a command line will install the COM+ applications (and get the correct reply from comadmin all three times) and the COM+ applications always work after that.

If something requires the COM+ applications to be installed, deleted, and installed again to work it somehow never happens on the other Web application's server.

The only rational explanation I can come up with is that something happens to the password on the way to comadmin (comadmin takes the password for the account running the COM+ applications as a parameter). But the password is quoted correctly in the build script and comadmin complains if the password for the account given is wrong, so the password must be correct.

Any ideas? (Or was I much too imprecise?)

Comment: This stopped happening at some point. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just stopped happening at some point...